# How to handle collisions with tile id javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, collision-detection

Ive written a small game in JavaScript with the html5 canvas and am at the point of collision detection and getting rather confused.

I build my levels in tiled and then import the saved JSON file into the game.

In my level draw function i have a check to see if there are any layer properties and if the layer properties are collisions. If it does, that layer is returned and the loop carries on. When finished, the layer that was returned with collisions gets put through another loop so that the the tile values can be put into an array.

So in this array i have i have a series of arrays depending on how many rows of tiles there are in the layer, and these rows hold the data for that row for each tile.

What i would like to do is when the player x/y is in one of the tiles which doesn't equal 0, then collide.

How would i do this if all i have is the value that is in that tile space?

[Here](http://upbeatevents.co.uk/dis) is a link to the live version of the game so you can see for yourself how the tiles are stored, i have put in some console.logs so you might want to use firebug or equivalent to look at that. To log in use

- Username - guest
- password - guest

TO clarify my question is: How do i create collisions between my player x/y and a tile value??
Thanks very much

**UPDATE**

Ok so i think im nearly there, my problem at the moment is how do i read the objects x and y out of the array and then check the collision, at the moment the collision detection on works with the last tile in the array (the bottom right of the screen), here is the code i implemented to go through the array:

```
this.check_coll = function(array,posX, posY){

    var collided = false,
        block_x,
        block_y,
        block_cx,
        block_cy,
        combined_hw = 32,
        combined_hh = 32,
        player_cx = posX+(32/2),
        player_cy = posY+(32/2);

    array.forEach(function(value,i){

            //get obj x
            block_x = value[1];
            //get obj y
            block_y = value[2];
            block_cx = block_x+(32/2);
            block_cy = block_y+(32/2);

        collided = Math.abs(player_cx - block_cx)< combined_hw
                 && Math.abs(player_cy - block_cy)< combined_hh;
    });

return collided;
}
```

Any ideas guys??

Comment: collided is outside of the forEach, which means that only the last assignment matters. maybe you can use `array.some` ?